# unable to connect to the docker daemon

Tags: python, docker, orchestration

I am using `python:3.8-buster` docker image for the project purpose in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` stage. I am trying to install docker for building the project using `docker build...` command but it is giving me the error:

```
docker_stage:
  image: python:3.8-buster
  stage: docker_stage
  script:
    - apt update
    - apt install docker.io -y
    - pip install awscli
    - service docker restart
    - service docker status
    - cd provisioner
    - docker build -t dbt_image .
    - docker tag dbt_image <ecr-uri>
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    - docker push <ecr-uri>
```

First of all the linux flavour is `Debian`. I have verified the docker is running via status command but still it doesn't connect to the docker daemon. It gives me below **error**:

```
time="2023-06-09T17:24:37Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
```

I have verified lots of posts on `SO` and also tried out the way on the local docker setup using the [official documentation for Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) but no luck. What else can be done here? Any help is much appreciated.